# Wordpress vps memory allocation

Tags: server, memory

I have a VPS sever for a wordpress site, which has an 8g ram and 4 cores cpu, however the site is really slow, I feel like the site is not using all resources, my question is, how much memory should the PHP sever limit be and how exactly can I do it? the server is in centos7.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to tell you that this all depends on the server size and the amount of resources your WordPress site uses. That being said, I set my php memory limit to between 256 and 512 MB.

WordPress sites can be slow for a large variety of reasons. Performance often improves by tweaking database settings (and checking for slow queries), configuring page and object caching, using a separate object cache like Redis or Memcache, adding Varnish in front of your site or using external edge cache like Cloudflare or Cloudfront, etc.